# When is the right time to say: "Now I need to create a user control!"

Tags: .net, controls, ascx

When do you consider creating a user control in .NET? Do you have some basic criteria to exclude your code from the page and introduce a new user control?

Usually I tend to follow those to decide whether I need a user control or not:

- When the page seems to be more readable with a separate user control
- When some part of the form looks like to be used from different pages again and again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose it follows the following:

- Do I need to separate this component out from the common code?
- Do I use this item often, meaning I need to keep recreating it?
- Do I need to be able to template this to suit different styles?

Answer (score 0):

I think the 2 reasons you provide are the main reasons anyone would create a user control. I really can't think of any other valid reasons...